# Conversion failed when converting the TEXT to INT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE pizza_recipes (
  "pizza_id" INTEGER,
  "toppings" TEXT
);
INSERT INTO pizza_recipes
  ("pizza_id", "toppings")
VALUES
  (1, '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10'),
  (2, '4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12');



CREATE TABLE pizza_toppings (
  "topping_id" INTEGER,
  "topping_name" TEXT
);
INSERT INTO pizza_toppings
  ("topping_id", "topping_name")
VALUES
  (1, 'Bacon'),
  (2, 'BBQ Sauce'),
  (3, 'Beef'),
  (4, 'Cheese'),
  (5, 'Chicken'),
  (6, 'Mushrooms'),
  (7, 'Onions'),
  (8, 'Pepperoni'),
  (9, 'Peppers'),
  (10, 'Salami'),
  (11, 'Tomatoes'),
  (12, 'Tomato Sauce')
```

and I'm asked : What are the standard ingredients for each pizza? (pizza_id 1 and 2)

So I guess I need to make a join to get the names of the different toppings of each pizza. But as you can see the toppings in pizza_recipes is TEXT and the topping_id in pizza_toppings is INTEGER.
So I'm trying to convert the TEXT to INTEGER, but I get error.

I already tried some solutions I saw in a similar post here, such as:

```
 SELECT convert(int, (convert( varchar(max),toppings))) as ColumnName
  FROM pizza_recipes

  SELECT CONVERT (INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),toppings)) FROM 
    FROM pizza_recipes

    select CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),toppings) AS INT)
FROM pizza_recipes
```

But they all keep giving me back Error. I'm new in SQL so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Is the general approach to the problem or is an error in the CAST or CONVERT queries?

Comment: Why are you using `text` at all? It was deprecated in SQL Server 2005; that was *18 years ago*. What "topping" is going to a value longer than 8,000 characters anyway?

Comment: Also, however, fix your design; **never** store delimited data in your database. Normalise your design and use approppriate data types, and this error won't happen.

Comment: You need to distinguish between pizzas, topping as tables and pizza-recipes table as relationship table (between pizzas and toppings) - this is already described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69365240/select-pizzas-with-toppings-sql?rq=2
where the user describes his tables and the join between those tables (that might give you a better understanding even though your question is different)

Comment: @ThomA um I'm not really sure about that, I'm new in this. All of this is part of a practice case, they gave me the tables and questions. You can check it out if you wish, 8weeksqlchallenge.com/case-study-2

Comment: @Twinnie ok I'll go check it out now

Comment: Who wrote that table design?  If it's a teacher or a co-worker I would question their knowledge (the data for "toppings" is not atomic, hence the table is not even in 1NF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options for how to do this. But it depends on what version of SQL server you are using and what format you are interested in.

**Dynamic SQL**

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = ''

select @sql = @sql + N'select '+cast(pizza_id as varchar)+' as pizza_id, * from pizza_toppings where topping_id in ('+cast(toppings as varchar)+')'+char(10)
from pizza_recipes

exec(@sql)
```

You can add union in dynamic string if you want to get one output. It's flexible

[image]

This variant requires SQL Server V2017 and higher due to `STRING_AGG`. If your version is lower, use `FOR XML` to create one string of toppings.

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = ''

select @sql = @sql + N'select '+cast(pizza_id as varchar)+', string_agg(cast(topping_name as varchar),'','') from pizza_toppings where topping_id in ('+cast(toppings as varchar)+')'+char(10)
from pizza_recipes
```

[image]

**`STRING_SPLIT()`**

It's simple but again SQL Server version should be 2017 and higher due to `STRING_SPLIT` function.

```
select pizza_id, string_agg(cast(topping_name as varchar),',') from pizza_recipes
inner join pizza_toppings on topping_id in (select [value] from string_split(cast(toppings as varchar), ','))
group by pizza_id
```

[image]

Comment: omg yess that's exaclty the results I needed! Thank you! (the second option) But now I'm confused by your Join  - on topping_id in (select [value]      from string_split(cast(toppings as varchar), ',')) - and why it works. Could you be so kind to explain it to me please? My questions are, Why only mention one column after the ON, Why Select [value], What does that mean and where does it come from? and why the join works when You havent make a connection of table.column = table.column ??

Comment: Hi Ale, `string_split` is a table-valued function. It means it returns a column of values. This column should have a name like any column in an ordinary table or view and, according to the official documentation, it is `value`. You can check it by the simple select: `select * from string_split('1,2,3', ',')`. Speaking of join, I made a connection between `topping_id` and `toppings`. You can join tables applying additional calculations. For example, `on column_year = year(column_date)`. I used the same technique but instead of `=` I put `in` because `string_split` returns one-column table.

Comment: I see, thank you so much for the explanation. I'll sit down and digest it hehe

Comment: Welcome! Here are the overview of [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql).  There are some interesting examples.

Comment: Oh great! thanks once again! :)